# Serializing Django models with non-model values

Tags: django, json, serialization

So I have this situation where i want to serialize models with non-model values. I got the serialization of the models [both queryset and single model itself] but trying to combine that with non-model values seem problematic.
for e.g. I want to JSONify `User` with some `status` of the request.
Assume `model_to_JSON` does model=>JSON, so

```
# it messes the 'user' json by further escaping it, 
#which becomes unparseble on client since its a string now
dumps({ 'user': model_to_JSON(user_obj), 'status': 'ok'})
```

I could do couple of hacks, by first doing `loads` on the converted model-json. but thats such a hacky way and so much time is just wasted in dumps=>loads=>dumps
second option is string concatenation by doing individuals dumps and then concatenate the strings by stripping '}' of the leftmost string and '{' of the rightmost string with ','.

The Django serializers are very specifically written towards models/queryset, so I can't really override them.

So has anyone faced this problem before and any solutions you could share

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [Django Full Serializers](http://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers), which was the approach I used a long, long time ago.

Another alternative would be to simply write your own serialisation function, that allows you to pass in attribute names (that will be looked up at serialisation time). I've done this, too. If you go down this approach, be aware there is already a django function `model_to_dict`, which does the pre-serialisation.

A third method might be to use django's forms as an intermediate to serialisation: this might be useful if you may be deserialising data back from the user, too.